# Extjs pass in parameters to window on show

Tags: extjs, window

I want to pass parameters to my window when I call window.show().

I added in a listener to my window for the show method but it's displaying the parameter as [Object, object].

```
 #window call
 var test = 'hi';
 tstWin.show(test);

 #listener
  listeners : {             
    'show' : function(test){
        alert(test.value);
     }   
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your event handler arguments will not be the same as you put into `show()` method. In fact they have nothing to do with each other.

Read this: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-show

Show event handler will receive in the first argument reference to the object.

Update:

You can do something like that:

```
win = Ext.create(...); // Create your window object here
win.myExtraParams = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}; // Add additional stuff
win.on('show', function(win) {
   console.log(win.myExtraParams.a, win.myExtraParams.b, win.myExtraParams.c);
});

win.show();
```

Comment: thanks that makes it a bit clearer. Do you know of anyway that you can pass params on/before showing a window?

Comment: It all depends on what exactly you are trying to do. Where do you need this parameter and what you will do with it?

Comment: the window contains a form and I'm passing in params from a grid when the window is opened to use with the form submission.

Comment: Add them as a property to the Window object and then access them later. I'm gonna update my answer with some code snippets

Comment: This is no longer valid in EXtJS 6. Check this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022475/passing-arguments-to-a-window-in-extjs-6