# How to show Extjs Window with title from a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs

I have this constructor:

```
 var sendMessagePopup = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Closing Doodad issue',
            id: 'sendMessagePopUpJS',
            width: 550,
            height: 435,
            loader: {
                url: "@Url.Action("SendMessagePopup", "Message")?subject=" + "@Model.Obj1.Model.Obj1Number - completed this" + "&messageBody=I will close this doodad.",
                loadMask: true,
                autoLoad: false,
                scripts: true,
                renderer: 'html'
            },
            autoScroll: true,
            resizable: false,
            layout: 'fit',
            closable: true,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            modal: true,
            header: true
        });
```

I get this window to show by calling this:

```
<a class="btn c10 buttonsRowForPreviewFixedWidth" onclick=" sendMessagePopup.show();
      sendCloseMessagePopup.loader.load(); ">Close Item</a>
```

This current works fine, but I want to re-use this for when a user would click on the opposite action : to open a doodad issue.  I've put two constructors for different windows on the page. but that is causing issues with the second one that contains the "Open Issue" literals not working properly.

The second button:

```
<a class="btn c10 buttonsRowForPreviewFixedWidth" onclick="sendOpenMessagePopup.show(); 
    sendOpenMessagePopup.loader.load(); ">Open Item</a>
```

How would I go about changing the title attribute, and some of the text in the loader when loading this window from a "Close this" or "Open This" button.

EDIT: I had a look at [Extjs pass in parameters to window on show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398087/extjs-pass-in-parameters-to-window-on-show?rq=1), but I cannot use the show().

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to re-use one component on two different occasions. In this case I would suggest using a component definition.

So instead of `Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {...})` you should use

```
Ext.define('sendMessagePopUpJS',
{
    extend      : 'Ext.window.Window',
    width: 550,
    height: 435,
```

etc.

Then you can create a new window on each click, and pass it some options, like

```
Ext.create('sendMessagePopUpJS', 
{
    title: 'foo'
}).show();
```