# extjs pass parameters to window

Tags: extjs, window

I'm unable to send data to a new window in extjs. Following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398087/extjs-pass-in-parameters-to-window-on-show), I've set a window property to the value I need in the new window:

```
function OpenAddSampleWindow(datasetid)
{
  var VIEW_WIDTH = $(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
  var VIEW_HEIGHT = $(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport



  win = Ext.create('widget.window', {
    title: 'Add Sample',
    id: 'AddSampleWindow',
    closable: true,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    width: VIEW_WIDTH,
    minWidth: 600,
    height: VIEW_HEIGHT,
    minHeight: 400,
    modal: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items : [{
       xtype : "component",
       autoScroll: true,
       autoEl : {
       tag : "iframe",
       src : "sample_add.html"
    }
  }]
 });
 win.datasetid=datasetid;
win.show();
return win;
}
```

Then, the javascript for the new window has the following function that runs when the page loads:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    alert(window.datasetid);
});
```

all that shows up in the alert box is "undefined"  I've also tried win.datasetid, but then I get an error that win is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I access this data?

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? console.log() does not output anything ? From what I see, this should work OK. Put a `debugger;` statement above the log statement and explore the `win` object.

Comment: I don't want the values output to the console.  I want them to be available to javascript functions for the new window.  Looking in the debugger, the win object has the data I expect.  I just don't know how to access it.

Comment: `javascriptFunction(win.myExtraParams.a, win.myExtraParams.b);` ?

Comment: win isn't defined within the new window...

Comment: Then post a new question or edit this one with the complete code and where you get the undefined error.

Comment: updated my question with my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

`window.datasetid` doesn't work because you are alerting a non-standard property on the browsers [window](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object.  `win.datasetid` probably doesn't work because you are not invoking the `OpenAddSampleWindow` function.  This is still bad practice though because you are using a global to get a reference to the win.  I think the better solution would be to not use a global.

```
    function OpenAddSampleWindow(datasetid)
{
  var VIEW_WIDTH = $(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
  var VIEW_HEIGHT = $(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport

  var win = Ext.create('widget.window', {
  //...
return win;
}
```

And invoke the function and then call the local variable whatever you want.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var winA2 = OpenAddSampleWindow('a1');
    alert(winA2.datasetid);
})
```

Comment: I guess I'm not clear with my question.  the Ext.onReady function is called when the new window is opened as a result of calling OpenAddSampleWindow. Your suggesting that within Ext.onReady() I call OpenAddSampleWindow with the datasetid as a parameter.  I don't have access to dataset id here, this is where I need to get it.  Also, I think what you're suggesting will result in an endless loop of opening new windows (as each new window will then call OpenAddSampleWindow)

Comment: I think I understand the question, you want to reference a global variable defined in a function that is never executed and it errors which it should.  `onReady` is called when the dom is ready, it has nothing to do with the new ext window being opened.  Please explain the endless loop possibility there is no way it should be endlessly looping.

Comment: I have multiple panels in my application.  In panel A, I collect the datasetid, and I want to pass that to panel B.  Panel B is created by the OpenAddSampleWindow function.  When panel B is created, onReady is called.  It is here, within panel B that I want access to datasetid.  If within panel B, I then call OpenAddSampleWindow, that will create a new panel (we'll call it C) that will then again call OpenAddSampleWindow ...   I want to get datasetid from panel A into panel B, and don't know how to do that.  The code I showed was based on the answer I referenced, and was the closest I had seen

Comment: Please read the documentation for onReady http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-onReady.  Good luck !