# Passing javascript array to new ExtJS popup window

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, extjs, extjs4

I have been trying to pass an image array as a parameter to a new ExtJS popup-window. I found this in the below link

[Extjs pass in parameters to window on show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398087/extjs-pass-in-parameters-to-window-on-show)

But when I tried this in my application, it says undefined. Below is my code.

```
    this.btnControlPDF = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {          
    width: 40,
    height:33,
    border:0,
    disabled : false,
    style: 'margin: 13px 1px 1px 5px;',
    cls : 'icon-button-ControllListButtonPDF',                        
    enableToggle: true,
    toggleGroup: 'AccumulateToolButtons',
    handler : function(myButton) {
        this.reportWindow = Ext.create('Ext.view.ReportExportView');
        this.reportWindow.myExtraParams = { imgArray : imgArray };
        this.reportWindow.show();
        return;
    }
});
```

Where Ext.view.ReportExportView extends Ext.window.Window

What I want is a way to pass a javascript array variable to new ExtJS popup window and be able to access that variable in the window.

I found HTML5 localStorage.getItem(). Can I use this to store my array?

Thank you!
Stu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you want the `myExtraParams` data to be accessed inside ReportExportView window and also from `this.reportWindow`. If so try this code.

```
 this.reportWindow = Ext.create('Ext.view.ReportExportView', {
                       myExtraParams : { imgArray : imgArray } 
                   } });
 this.reportWindow.show();
```

Way to access `myExtraParams` from `ReportExportView`.

```
Ext.define('Ext.view.ReportExportView', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.reportwindoww',
    width: 500,
    height: 250,
    layout: 'fit',
    initComponent: function(){
       console.log(this.myExtraParams);
       //You can write the remaining code here.
       this.items = [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            ...............
            ...............
       }];
       this.callParent(arguments);  
    }
 });
```

Comment: But how do I access it in the popup window?

Comment: Use `initComponent `method in `ReportExportView` definition. With in that, you can just read it like `this.myExtraParams`. I shall add some code sample if you need.

Comment: What I added is var imgsArr = me.myExtraParams.imgArray; in the popup window and it worked! Thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)