# Passing arguments to a window in ExtJs 6?

Tags: extjs, window

I would like to a pass a record from a grid to a window that I create,

```
Ext.create('MyWindow',
    {recordRef: record}).show();
```

where `record` is an argument that is passed into my `rowdblclick` function but when I try to access `recordRef` (like below) during debugging, it is undefined.

```
var me = this;
var record = me.getView().recordRef;
```

The code fragment above is in a controller for `MyWindow.js`

Comment: Your code fragment looks fine. What kind of function does it belongs to and how is it called?

Comment: What event are you using to call your controller method that is trying to access `view.recordRef`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is probably because you are using an event to access `recordRef` that is called before the constructor assigns `recordRef` to your window as a property.

My advice would be to use the `show` event just to be sure, here is a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/232m

Answer (score 0):

You can access custom configs you add to a component with [getConfig](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.2/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#method-getConfig) - in this case it would be `this.getConfig('recordRef')`

[Here's a small fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2300) where the custom config is logged to the console, and set to be the window's title.